# Building an adequate statical model

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, generalized-estimating-equations

My question is: What statistical model can I use to meet my objective and how can I specify it properly?

DV: MuscleMass
VIs: Age, sex, Intervention (control vs interventions (1 to 7)), and Time.

Background:  I have access to individual data from 7 different studies. The first study has measurements of the variables of interest at baseline and 5 days after intervention. the second, third and fourth have measurements at baseline and 21 days after the interventions. the fifth, sixth and seventh are baseline measurements, 15, 30 and 60 days after the intervention. Individuals are different between studies and each study evaluates a different type of intervention. My objective is to evaluate the impact of time and intervention according to age and sex on muscle mass.

This is a simulated data base:

````
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Simulating individual data for each study
# Study 1: Baseline and 5 days after intervention
study1 <- data.frame(
  Study = rep(1, 100),                      # Study identifier
  ID = rep(paste0("S1_", 1:50), each = 2) 
)
study1 <- study1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Intervention = rep(sample(c("Intervention1", "Control"), size = 1), 2),
         Time = rep(c("Baseline", "5days"), each = 1),
         Age = rep(round(runif(1, 30, 60)), 2),
         Sex = rep(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1), 2),
         MuscleMass = rnorm(2, 60, 10))


# Study 2, 3, and 4: Baseline and 21 days after intervention
study2 <- data.frame(
  Study = rep(2, 100),                     # Study identifier
  ID = rep(paste0("S2_", 1:50), each = 2)
)
study2 <- study2 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Intervention = rep(sample(c("Intervention2", "Control"), size = 1), 2),
    Time = rep(c("Baseline", "21days"), each = 1),
         Age = rep(round(runif(1, 50, 75)), 2),
         Sex = rep(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1), 2),
         MuscleMass = rnorm(2, 55, 10))

study3 <- data.frame(
  Study = rep(3, 100),                     # Study identifier
  ID = rep(paste0("S3_", 1:50), each = 2)
)
study3 <- study3 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Intervention = rep(sample(c("Intervention3", "Control"), size = 1), 2),
    Time = rep(c("Baseline", "21days"), each = 1),
         Age = rep(round(runif(1, 45, 80)), 2),
         Sex = rep(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1), 2),
         MuscleMass = rnorm(2, 54, 10))

study4 <- data.frame(
  Study = rep(4, 100),                     # Study identifier
  ID = rep(paste0("S4_", 1:50), each = 2) 
)
study4 <- study4 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Intervention = rep(sample(c("Intervention4", "Control"), size = 1), 2),
    Time = rep(c("Baseline", "21days"), each = 1),
         Age = rep(round(runif(1, 73, 85)), 2),
         Sex = rep(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1), 2),
         MuscleMass = rnorm(2, 30, 10))
# Study 5, 6, and 7: Baseline and 60 days after intervention
study5 <- data.frame(
  Study = rep(5, 100),                     # Study identifier
  ID = rep(paste0("S5_", 1:50), each = 2) 
)
study5 <- study5 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Intervention = rep(sample(c("Intervention5", "Control"), size = 1), 2),
    Time = rep(c("Baseline", "60days"), each = 1),
         Age = rep(round(runif(1, 63, 88)), 2),
         Sex = rep(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1), 2),
         MuscleMass = rnorm(2, 35, 10))

study6 <- data.frame(
  Study = rep(6, 100),                     # Study identifier
  ID = rep(paste0("S6_", 1:50), each = 2) 
)
study6 <- study6 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Intervention = rep(sample(c("Intervention6", "Control"), size = 1), 2),
    Time = rep(c("Baseline", "60days"), each = 1),
         Age = rep(round(runif(1, 45, 90)), 2),
         Sex = rep(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1), 2),
         MuscleMass = rnorm(2, 46, 10))

study7 <- data.frame(
  Study = rep(7, 100),                     # Study identifier
  ID = rep(paste0("S7_", 1:50), each = 2) 
)
study7 <- study7 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Intervention = rep(sample(c("Intervention7", "Control"), size = 1), 2),
    Time = rep(c("Baseline", "60days"), each = 1),
         Age = rep(round(runif(1, 70, 92)), 2),
         Sex = rep(sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1), 2),
         MuscleMass = rnorm(2, 25, 10))

# Combining the individual data from all studies
combined_data <- rbind(study1, study2, study3,study4,study5,study6,study7)
rm(study1, study2, study3,study4,study5,study6,study7)
```
````